# Webgrid pager gone after hiding a column Mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Webgrid in Mvc4 , where I want to hide a column in. 
The problem is that when I hide the column, the paging is disappearing, and I do not know why.

My webgrid looks like this:

```
                                    @{
                                    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridcontent");
                                    grid.Bind(source: Model.Projects, rowCount: Model.RowCount, autoSortAndPage: false);
                                    grid.PageIndex = Model.ProjectPage;
                                    grid.SortColumn = Model.SortColumn;
                                    grid.SortDirection = Model.SortDirectionForColumn;
                                }

                                <div id="gridcontent">
                                    @grid.GetHtml(
                                    fillEmptyRows: false,
                                        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                                        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                                        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                                        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                                        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                                        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                                        htmlAttributes: new { id = "MainTable" },
                                        columns: grid.Columns(
                                            grid.Column("VsuProjectId", "Project Id"),
                                            grid.Column("ProjectName", " Project " + VsuWebPortal.Models.WebgridHelper.SortDirection(null, ref grid, "ProjectName"), style: "columnWidth"),
                                            grid.Column("CountryName", "Country", style: "columnWidth"),

                                            grid.Column("CustomerName", "Customer Name" style: "columnWidth"),
                                            grid.Column("CRMId", "CRM Id", style: "columnWidth"),

                                            grid.Column("MainProjectVersion", "Project Version", canSort: false, style: "columnwswithNotSortable")
                                            ))
```

And the javascript function for hiding a column is;

```
function hideColumnColorRow(column) {
   $('td:nth-child(' + column + '),th:nth-child( ' + column + ')').hide();
}
```

I have also tried to do it with Css, which did hide the column, but gave the same result with paging.

```
table th:first-child, table td:first-child {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out why it did hide the paging in the footer, but I managed to make it work.
Somehow, it only hide the footer when I wanted to hide the first column.
So instead of using:

```
table th:first-child, table td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

I used:

```
table td:nth-child(10), table th:nth-child(10) {
  display: none;
}
```

And now it worked just fine.
The reason for having a hidden column in the table was that it was used when I clicked on the whole row:

```
$(function () {
var tr = $('#MainTable').find('tbody tr');
tr.live('hover', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
  }).live('click', function () {

      location.href = 'Whut/Details/' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(10)').text();

  });
});
```